# How to insert list elements inside tuples in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose

```
list1 = [('WAIT=', '6'), ('WAIT=', '1'), ('WAIT=', '1')]
list2 = [12,2,2]
```

Taking note that list1 and list2 will always have an equal number of elements, how do I replace the 2nd element in each tuple in list1 with the elements in list2? That is:

```
[('WAIT=', 12), ('WAIT=', 2), ('WAIT=', 2)]
```

Comment: If every tuple starts with "WAIT=", then you can do this: `[("WAIT=", x) for x in list2]`

Comment: @coldspeed Woah! I just stepped out for lunch and got tons of ways to do exactly what i need! Thanks guys. I'm choosing U9-Forward's answer as it's the first actual answer, i guess. Again, thanks heaps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a list comprehension with a `zip` within, then get first value of each value of `list1` list as first element, and each `list2` value as second element:

```
print([(x[0],y) for x,y in zip(list1,list2)])
```

Output:

```
[('WAIT=', 12), ('WAIT=', 2), ('WAIT=', 2)]
```

Comment: It may be good to note that you're creating new tuples using this as modifying tuples (while doable) isn't worth the effort in this case.

Comment: @Jaba Thanks for telling me, got it, but at least it works :-), thanks for replying too!

Comment: Haha, I know it took forever, actually didn't even realize it was you I was correcting! lol I explained why it took me so long too

Comment: @Jaba Lol, at least happy to hear from you :-) :D

Comment: We need a way to chat, emails feel outdated haha

Comment: @Jaba Now i have a hat on because of Winter Bash, on my snail's head

Comment: @Jaba well, yeah, don't know where tho. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185100/discussion-between-jaba-and-u9-forward).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do the same is as follows (it will allow you to have a new list with any value of 1st item in each tuple, `WAIT=`, `WAIT1=` etc.):

```
list1 = [('WAIT=', '6'), ('WAIT=', '1'), ('WAIT=', '1')]
list2 = [12,2,2]

for i, n in enumerate(list2):  
    list1[i] = (list1[i][0], n) 

print(list1) 
# [('WAIT=', 12), ('WAIT=', 2), ('WAIT=', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `operator`

```
import operator
l1 = map(operator.itemgetter(0), list1)
list(zip(l1,list2))
[('WAIT=', 12), ('WAIT=', 2), ('WAIT=', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since tuple object does not support item assignment, I suppose that we would need to create a new list of tuple. You might use this one line to get the result.

```
[(slice[0], replacement) for slice, replacement in zip(list1, list2)]
```